# Referencing an associated table in an ActiveRecord where/join call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

Lets say I have two Rails models, Users and Lists. Users have_many lists and lists belong_to a user.

Users also have one particular list they are working on at any given time. This is denoted by the active_list_id foreign key on the User model.

Let's say I want to run the equivalent of the following query via ActiveRecord:

```
SELECT * FROM users JOIN lists 
ON lists.id = users.active_list_id
```

Basically I am trying to write a method which will get each user, along with her currently active list, to display statistics on list completion.

The solution seems to me to be something like

```
Users.joins(:lists).where("users.active_list_id  = lists.id")
```

But I can't seem to get that to work**, and I'm not sure what the most idiomatically correct solution is in Rails.

How should I pull this data most efficiently and effectively using ActiveRecord?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

EDIT: The above query does work, but does not seem to pull a conjunction of the user record and its associated list.

Comment: usually the table names would be "users" and "lists" -- could that be your problem?

Comment: Good call, but no, that was my mistake. The tables are in fact lowercase. I'll edit my question for clarity, thank you.

Comment: I misunderstood, the problem is the query not the tables. You are correct, that query without the capitalization returns the users i need, however it does not seem to include the list record as well.

Comment: darn.  Well, what you're doing looks correct.  Have you tried that SQL in the mysql console?  Have you tried making a simpler where clause (say, 'lists.id = 1' or something trivial) to try to isolate where it's breaking down?

Comment: I did try that in the sql console (sqlite actually)...The query in SQL returns both table records joined...*headscratch*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some strangr things on your post. First thing is: "have_many" thats wrong its called `has_many` that might be a problem if its in your model like you wrote it down! Then the other thing is the name of the foreign key! The foreign key by convention is the name of the association in singular with addition of _id. When you say you want to hasv `user.lists` the foreign key must be called `list_id` and not `active_list_id`! You can specify an not conventional foreign key by passing the `foreign_key` option in the association! That would look like this:

User.rb:

```
has_many :lists, :foreign_key => 'active_list_id'
```

List.rb:

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'active_list_id'
```

Then you would be able to say it like this:

```
User.find(<id>).lists
```

You NEVER EVER join tables in rails using SQL! Dont try to transfer PHP knowlage to RoR 1 to 1, just dont!

// Ahh now I understand what you ceed is a scope with parameters!
User.rb:

```
scope :active_list, lambda{|list_id| where(:active_list_id =>  list_id)}
```

Then you could call `User.active_list(<list_id>)` to get all the users using this list!

Comment: Indeed, that have_many was a momentary lapse of reason, its not actually like that in my model...And to think I read the question about five times >_<...The active_list_id isnt a foreign key used in the association between users and lists, per se, its in addition to the user_id column on the lists model. It helps me reference which specific list is currently active. Is that logical?

Comment: Cheers, this is great, I think using a scope will keep the code DRYer, and considering that I'll probably use that scope a lot, that fits the project quite well. Thanks a lot =)

Comment: Be aware that using a `lambda` invites performance issues.  In some uses of a RDMBS, lambda can load all of the data into memory, and then loop through it for the conditions.

Comment: The `lambda` problem is sometimes called and `N+1` problem, and [is identified in the Rails Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: Never say never, except to say "Never say never"

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Users.includes(:lists).where("users.active_list_id  = lists.id")
```

what you're doing in your question is loading the users that match that criteria, while what you want is to [eager-load the association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) as well

Though really, you might want to consider making this a separate association:

```
class User
  belongs_to :active_list, :class_name => :list
end

class List
  has_one :user
end
```

Comment: This works in that it allows me to plug the result into a variable and then crawl through them finding the completion statistics for each one and ranking them accordingly. I'm wondering whether its better to do it in this fashion or to make one query which tacks on the necessary fields to the result (i.e. adds lists.pct_completed to each User record)...In any case, thank you for your assistance.